# How to loaded survey form dynamically in android from url?

Tags: android, survey

i need to know how to load Survey Form dynamically from my web url and show it in android.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

in your `OnCreate()` method use following code

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl("http://www.tutorialspoint.com");
```

Tutorial for implementing the complete solution : [Open URL in WebView](http://androidexample.com/Show_Loader_To_Open_Url_In_WebView__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=125&aaid=145).

Comment: there are about 40 pages, will this be useful?

Comment: According to me it will solve your question but it depends on you is it will solving your issue or not.